# Call subitems of a plist

Tags: ios, swift, plist

This is my property list: [directory.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAyf6.png)

I would like to know how call the subitems into a ViewController. This is my actual ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class Page1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var positionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        Shared.instance.employees.forEach({

            nameLabel.text = (("name:", $0.name) as? String)

            print("name:", $0.name)
            print("position:", $0.position)
            print("phone:", $0.phone)
            print("email:", $0.email)
            print()
        })
    }
}
```

And this is the Struct I am using:

```
import UIKit

struct Employee {
    let position: String
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let phone: String
    init(dictionary: [String: String]) {
        self.position = dictionary["Position"] ?? ""
        self.name = dictionary["Name"] ?? ""
        self.email = dictionary["Email"] ?? ""
        self.phone = dictionary["Phone"] ?? ""
    }
}

struct Shared {
    static var instance = Shared()
    var employees: [Employee] = []
}
```

Inside the AppDelegate I put this:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "directory", withExtension: "plist"), let array = NSArray(contentsOf: url) as? [[String: String]] {
            Shared.instance.employees = array.map{Employee(dictionary: $0)}
    }
    return true
```

I do I have to do to call the subitems on my directory.plist? I mean the items inside the **key Details**. Then I wanna show the Func1, Func2 and Func3.

*obs.: (this func is an abbreviation of functionary)*

Thanks!

---

After some changes, now I got the Subitems nil: [debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxjrw.png)

Comment: I must be misreading the problem. As I read it you're asking how to get an employees name by calling employee.name or his position by calling employee.position. Of course you'd have to change that since you're putting your data ref in the app delegate for some reason.

Comment: Both. I only don't know what changes I have to do in the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the application delegate is fine. You just need to update your `Employee` struct with another property to store the `Details`. But this also means that your employee dictionary isn't just a dictionary of string values. So you need to update the code to handle the proper value types:

```
struct Employee {
    let position: String
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let phone: String
    let details: [String:String]

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.position = (dictionary["Position"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.name = (dictionary["Name"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.email = (dictionary["Email"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.phone = (dictionary["Phone"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.details = (dictionary["Details"] as? [String:String]) ?? [:]
    }
}
```

Comment: Then do I have to create a **Struct Detail** including the functionaries?

Comment: No. You can do something like `print("func1 = \($0.details["func1"])")`.

Comment: You can create a `Detail` struct if you wish but it's not needed. It's really up to you and your needs.

Comment: I got it, I am gonna try without a new Struct. The more simple, the best! lol

Comment: I did it, but now I having two error message. 1st in Struct: `Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '[String : String]?'`. And 2nd in View Controller: `Cast from '(String, String)' to unrelated type 'String' always fails`. Any idea?

Comment: Without seeing your updated code and which line is causing the error, it's hard to say. Edit your question with an update showing your updated details.

Comment: @ArnonRodrigues I see the issue. The problem is that the employee dictionary was declared as a `[String:String]` when it is really a `[String:Any]` since the most values are `String` but the Details value is another dictionary. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Great, working! But the debugger shows my subitems `nil`. I just updated the question.

Comment: Make sure you use the correct key. It needs to be "Func1", etc., not "func1". It has to match what you have in the plist.

Comment: That was the problem! I am sorry, this is working now. Later I am going to make another question treating about receiving an image from that plist.